Comparing human estimates and algorithm on normalized score
By means of an algorithm, we want to predict a metric value $Y$ that can vary for different items $i=1,\ldots,n$. The quantities $y_i$ have been estimated by $N$ human annotators and we want to compute a performance score for an algorithm.
The mean squared or absolute errors (MSE, MAE) with respect to the human average are not good indices for the algorithm accuracy because $y_i$ can vary considerably, and an error of, e.g. 5 is good for $y_i=50$, but poor for $y_i=6$. To make the scale of the $y_i$ comparable and take care of the variance in the human estimations, we thought of computing a z-score*) for each algorithm result and then average over all z-scores. This has the problem, however, that the variance between the humans is zero for some items.
*) with $z=\frac{y_{alg} \;-\; \overline{y_i}}{\hat{\sigma}_i}$ with $\overline{y_i}$ and $\hat{\sigma}_i$ estimated from the human results.
Is there some established "normalized error" for this situation? Note that we are not interested in a p-value, i.e. whether there is a difference, but how strong the difference is.

Are your target values all positive? If not, how bad is an error of 5 for an actual of -5 or for -50?

What is this algorithm that you mention? Is this some reference score?

@StephanKolassa Yes all values are positive integers, although they can be zero.

@user2974951 The algorithm estimates the number of persons in a (possibly crowded) scene.

So is this a comparison then between computer vision and humans estimating how many people are in a scene? Why not compare the human scores with the computer scores?

Hm. If your data were all positive, you could use the MAPE. But it's not defined when actuals are zero, though there are workarounds. And it will reward heavily biased predictions in your situation of a high CoV.

@user2974951 "Why not compare the human scores with the computer scores?" That is the task. As explained in the question, simply taking the average of the human scores and comparing it to the computer score ignores the varying spread in the human scores, plus it is not scale invariant.

@StephanKolassa Thanks for the link to the insightful remarks concerning MAPE. Yes, switching to the relative error solves the scaling problem, and the problem of division by zero is avoided if the normalization is done with the greater of the values. It does not take into account the error in the human estimates, though.
